# Trying to create a custom page tab... can't add the app to a page

Tags: tabs, facebook-apps, fan-page

I'm trying to create a relatively basic custom fan page tab with Developer, and for some reason I'm unable to add the app to any pages. In the past with other similar , I've had a "view app profile page" link on the left, but for some reason it's not showing up.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

> Go to: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL` where `YOUR_APP_ID` is found in your app settings, and `YOUR_URL` is indeed the URL of the tab (this has to be there an correct). This will take you to the Add to Page Dialog of your page.

This is taken from this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

If you want to make a button so that anyone can add the tab to their pages check DMCS' link.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/